# A multiple group by and multiple display count on spark sql?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new at Spark and I just want to ask you please this question related to Spark SQL. Let's consider this EMPLOYEE table :

```
Employee     Sub_department   Department 
A               105182          10
A               105182          10   (data can be redundant !)   
A               114256          11
A               127855          12
A               125182          12
B               136234          13
B               133468          13
```

*Department is defined as substring(sub_department, 0, 2) to extract only the first 2 digits of the sub_department.*

What I want to display is to divide 3 types of employees :

- Set 1 : Employees having at least 3 different departments (regardless of their sub_departments)
- Set 1 : Employees having at least 5 different sub_departments AND 2 different departments
- Set 3 : Employees having at least 10 different sub_departments with the same department

Concretely I have no idea how to do this even in classical SQL. But at least, I think the final output can be something like this :

```
Employee     Sub_department   total_sub_dept  Department  total_dept 
A               105182          4                10           3     
A               114256          4                11           3
A               127855          4                12           3
A               125182          4                12           3
```

And "eventually" a column named "Set" to show in which set an employee can belong to, but it's optional and I'm scared it will be too heavy to compute such a value...

It's important to display the different values AND the count for each of the 2 columns (the sub_department and the department).

I have a very big table (with many columns and many data that can be redundant) so I thought to do this by using a first partition on the sub_department and store it on a first table. Then a second partition on the department (regardless the "sub_department" value) and store it on a second table. And finally, do an inner joint between the two table based on the employee name.

But I got some wrong results and I don't know if there is a better way to do this ? or at least to have an optimisation since the department column depends on the sub_department (to do one group by rather than 2).

So, how can I fix this? I tried but it seems impossible to combine count(column) with the same column for each of the 2 columns.

Comment: It will be really helpful if you could add the query you have written so far. As per my knowledge, people on SO won't really give you ready made query which you can just copy paste in your cluster.

Answer (score 1):

I'll help you out with the requirement in set 1 just to encourage you. Please try to understand below query, once done, it is very simple to do set 2 and set 3.

```
SELECT 
 employee
 total_dept
FROM
(
 SELECT
  employee
  COUNT(Department) AS total_dept
 FROM
 (
  select 
    employee,
    Sub_department,
    SUBSTRING(Sub_department,0,2) AS Department,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by employee,SUBSTRING(Sub_department,0,2)) AS redundancy 
  FROM
  table
 )
 WHERE redundancy = 1
 GROUP BY employee
) WHERE total_dept >= 3
```

EDIT1:

```
SELECT 
 full_data.employee,
 full_data.sub_department,
 total_sub_dept_count.total_sub_dept
 full_data.SUBSTRING(Sub_department,0,2) AS Department
 total_dept_count.total_dept
FROM
(
 SELECT
  employee
  COUNT(Department) AS total_dept
 FROM
 (
  select 
    employee,
    Sub_department,
    SUBSTRING(Sub_department,0,2) AS Department,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by employee,SUBSTRING(Sub_department,0,2)) AS redundancy 
  FROM
  employee_table
 )
 WHERE redundancy = 1
 GROUP BY employee
) total_dept_count
JOIN
(
 SELECT
  employee
  COUNT(department) AS total_sub_dept
 FROM
 (
  select 
    employee,
    department,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by employee,department) AS redundancy 
  FROM
  employee_table
 )
 WHERE redundancy = 1
 GROUP BY employee
) total_sub_dept_count
ON(total_dept_count.employee = total_sub_dept_count.employee)
JOIN
 employee_table full_data
ON(total_sub_dept_count.employee = full_data.employee)
```

Comment: Thank for your answer but it's not exactly what I wanted. In fact, I think that just dispalying "employee and the total_dept" is less difficult that displaying together "dept" column AND its total. In addition, I am able to do one partition in one request but to do two partitions (for set 2 or 3 for example) is less obvious... I will post later my previous code to give you an idea about what I have done so far

Comment: If you still want to have the output same as your expectations, I can give you a fix, but it is a very costly operation. I've added the same in the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the window functions collect_set() and get the results. Check this out

```
scala> val df = Seq(("A","105182","10"), ("A","105182","10" ), ("A","114256","11"), ("A","127855","12"), ("A","125182","12"), ("B","136234","13"), ("B","133468","13")).toDF("emp","subdept","dept")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [emp: string, subdept: string ... 1 more field]

scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- emp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- subdept: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dept: string (nullable = true)


scala> df.show
+---+-------+----+
|emp|subdept|dept|
+---+-------+----+
|  A| 105182|  10|
|  A| 105182|  10|
|  A| 114256|  11|
|  A| 127855|  12|
|  A| 125182|  12|
|  B| 136234|  13|
|  B| 133468|  13|
+---+-------+----+


scala> val df2 = df.withColumn("dept2",substring('subdept,3,7))
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [emp: string, subdept: string ... 2 more fields]

scala> df2.createOrReplaceTempView("salaman")

scala> spark.sql(""" select *, size(collect_set(subdept) over(partition by emp)) sub_dep_count, size(collect_set(dept) over(partition by emp)) dep_count from salaman """).show(false)
+---+-------+----+-----+-------------+---------+
|emp|subdept|dept|dept2|sub_dep_count|dep_count|
+---+-------+----+-----+-------------+---------+
|B  |136234 |13  |6234 |2            |1        |
|B  |133468 |13  |3468 |2            |1        |
|A  |105182 |10  |5182 |4            |3        |
|A  |105182 |10  |5182 |4            |3        |
|A  |125182 |12  |5182 |4            |3        |
|A  |114256 |11  |4256 |4            |3        |
|A  |127855 |12  |7855 |4            |3        |
+---+-------+----+-----+-------------+---------+


scala>
```